# How to make a function that takes both Activity and Fragment as the context for an argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have the following function that can take an activity as an argument and when I call it from an `Activity` it works perfectly. Now that I want to call this function from a fragment but I can see there is an error in the editor saying 'Incompatible types: CargoFragment and Activity'. I tried replacing `activity: Activity` with `context: Context`.

The error I have is at 'is CargoFragment'

```
    fun getProductList(activity: Activity) {
        mFireStore.collection("abc")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { 
                .....
                .....
                .....

                    productList.add(product)
                }
                when (activity) {
                    is CargoActivity -> {
                        activity.success(productList)
                    }
                    is CheckoutActivity -> {
                        activity.success(productList)
                    }
                    is CargoFragment -> {
                        activity.success(productList)
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.d("CheckTag", e.message!!)
                when (activity) {
                    is CargoActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                    is CheckoutActivity -> {
                        activity.hideProgressDialog()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add more context to your problem? What are you trying to achieve? Where do you have this `activity.success(...)` function?

Comment: As you can see `CargoActivity` and `CheckoutActivity` are two `activitie`s and `CargoFragment` is a `fragment`. The above function is in another `class` called 'FirestoreFunctions.kt'

Comment: Add the part of code from where you are calling this function.

Comment: Might I suggest using this: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass `activity` to `getProductList`. As far as I understand, you are passing `activity` to execute some code when you get a response (success or failure). A better way to implement this is to expose callback lambdas.

Consider this approach:

```kotlin
fun getProductList(onSuccess: (List<Product>) -> Unit, onFailure:() -> Unit) {
    mFireStore.collection("abc")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                ...                  
                    productList.add(product)
                }
                onSuccess(productList)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                ...
                onFailure()
            }
}
```

Usage (in your activity and fragment):

```kotlin
getProductList(
    onSuccess = { list ->
        success(list) // whatever you want to do on success
    },
    onFailure = {
        hideProgressBar() // whatever you want to do on failure
    }
)
```

Comment: This is something new to me. Is this a better approach than mine?

Comment: Yes. This will decouple your Firebase code with your UI layer. And makes it more useable. Your firebase code does not need to depend upon your activity. It can just invoke the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` lambda whenever it is done. So instead of letting `getProductList` decide what to do on success and failure, a better approach is to let the callers decide what to do.

Comment: The list is always empty, I have been checking if I could fix it myself but I couldn't.

Comment: Log `productList` in your `getProductList` function. Verify if you are even the getting the list from firebase or not.

Comment: I Logged in many places but I didn't get the list of items, I was thinking about why I am not getting the data from the Firestore the very moment you commented. But, with my old code, I am still getting the data. Anyway, let me check once more and will get back to you.

Comment: That was my bad, There's a typo in my `Collection`s name

Comment: Everything working now?

Comment: Awesome. Working good.

Answer (score 0):

if this is your viewModel, then u should NEVER have refernce to any context/activity/fragment.

Best approach would be to to have a liveData to hold progress states and let UI (activity or fragment)  observe this.

Answer (score 0):

No need to change anything in function parameter.
Call it from activity
`getProductList(this)`
and call it from fragment
`getProductList(getActivity())`.

Comment: I tried `FirestoreFunctions().getProductList(requireActivity())` when calling it from the `fragment` but still the `Incompatible types: CargoFragment and Activity`appears.

Comment: If CargoFragment extends androidx.fragment.app.Fragment then requireActivity() should work. I have tried this myself.