# How to use the same RecyclerView adapter with Activity and Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have created an app that works perfectly. I decided to make some changes to my app, that is, use `Fragment` instead of `Activity` at some places. This activity has a `RecyclerView` in it and that is used to load data which is fetched from the `Firestore`. Everything will remain the same except `Fragment` will be used instead of `Activity`.

Now the problem I have is with the `recyclerView` adapter where it takes context.

```
open class CargoListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Cargo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

When a button is clicked, I have to check the context to take further action accordingly.

```
            holder.binding.ibDelete.setOnClickListener {

            when (context) {
                is OrderActivity -> {
                    val activity = holder.itemView.context as? OrderActivity

                    activity?.viewSpecialRequest(
                        model.custom_request
                    )
                }

                is MyOrderDetailsActivity -> {
                    val activity = holder.itemView.context as? MyOrderDetailsActivity

                    activity?.viewSpecialRequest(
                        model.custom_request
                    )
                }

                is CargoFragment -> {
                    val activity = holder.itemView.context as? CargoFragment

                    activity?.editDeleteSpecialRequestDialog(
                        holder.binding.ibEditDeleteNote,
                        holder.binding.ibAddNote,
                        model.id,
                        model.custom_request
                    )

                }
            }
        }
```

This is how I am calling from one of the activities.

```
val cargoListAdapter = CargoListAdapter(this@OrderActivity, mCargoList)
```

I tried to call from the `fragment` like below but I can see an error "Incompatible types: CargoFragment and Context" at `is CargoFragment -> {`

```
val cargoListAdapter = CargoListAdapter(requireContext(), mCargoList)
```

**EDIT:
This is not part of the question but to show what I have done when there are a couple of buttons in the `recyclerView` and take action depending on which button is clicked. Someone has already asked about it in the accepted answer's comment box.**

Now the `onClickItem` of the adapter class is changed as per my requirement. Where, as you can see, I have `action:String` and which will let me know which button is clicked and what function/action needs to be done further.

```
open class CargoListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Cargo>,
    private val onClickItem: (pos: Int,addButton: ImageButton,deleteButton: ImageButton,model: Cargo,action:String) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>()
```

In the `onBindViewHolder` I have the following.

```
 holder.binding.ibRemoveItem.setOnClickListener {
                        onClickItem(holder.adapterPosition,
                            holder.binding.ibAddNote,
                            holder.binding.ibDeleteNote,
                            model,
                            "removeItem")
}
```

Whenever a button is clicked a button `onClickListener` is set up as above and depending on the button I change the value for 'action'. As you can see, in the above example, it's 'removeItem' and hence from the below code the action that comes under 'removeItem' will take place.
Following is what I have in the 'CargoFragment'

```
when (action) {
"DeleteNote" -> {
 ///TAKE SOME ACTION HERE
}
"AddNote" -> {
///TAKE SOME ACTION HERE
 }
"removeItem" -> {
///TAKE SOME ACTION HERE
}
```

This is what I have done to handle the situation where there are multiple buttons in the `recyclerView` and it's working without any flaws. I hope some experts will comment on this so that beginners can know whether this is OK to follow.

Comment: I think you need to replace `requireContext()` with `this@CargoFragment` because the fragment is not a context, and therefore `context is CargoFragment ->` will have type mismatch

Comment: Why don't you try something similar to what I suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69962693/13308991) answer of your question? Pass a callback lambda to you Adapter and let the caller decide what to do when that lambda is invoked.

Comment: As I said there, that was something new to me as a beginner. I changed a couple of similar functions the way you suggested. But, this is totally a different thing, an adapter, I do not want to spoil all my code in there trying to implement your version myself. By the way, I like your code and will use the same version for all new codes, wherever I can.

Comment: @Zain For that,  I have to change the parameter 'context' of the adapter class to `CargoFragment`. Which I cannot do as the same adapter is used by activities too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an interface and accessing function by using Activity or Fragment instance you can use Kotlin higher order functions to make the adapter independent and use it anywhere in the code.

```
open class CargoListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Cargo>,
    private val onClickItem:(pos: Int, viewId: Int) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
```

Call onClickItem in ViewHolder on click :

```
    holder.binding.ibDelete.setOnClickListener {
        onClickItem(adapterPosition, it.id)
    }

    holder.binding.ibEdit.setOnClickListener {
        onClickItem(adapterPosition, it.id)
    }
```

In Activity or Fragment :

```
adapter = CargoListAdapter(context, list){position, viewId->
   //receive click here
    when(viewId){
        R.id.ibDelete -> //Delete Action
        R.id.ibEdit -> //Delete Action
        // You can use sam click listener for multiple views by passing id
    }
}
```

Checkout this gist for complete adapter example : https://github.com/Noddy20/Gists/blob/master/RecyclerViewAdapter-1.kt

Comment: if I need to click three more buttons for example not just the delete button, how can I do it? to write three kotlin functions?

Comment: @Yura Please find details after 'EDIT' in my question. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just like I have passed the pos: Int for item position you can also pass another parameter for the view id that is clicked. Than in Activity/Fragment use that view Id (with condition when/if/else) to perform the action you need.

Comment: @Yura Updated the answer for multiple view clicks.

Answer (score 0):

you check the context and then convert it to activity or fragment where the adapter was created, and after you call activity/fragment method `viewSpecialRequest` this is not very correct, if you want to call activity/fragment methods after click on `ibDelete` you need to add for example an interface.

```
open class CargoListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Cargo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

interface OnItemActionsListener {
        fun onDeleteClicked()
    }

var onItemActionsListener:OnItemActionsListener? =null

 holder.binding.ibDelete.setOnClickListener {
     onItemActionsListener?.onDeleteClicked()
 } 

********* 
 }
}
```

OrderActivity

```
adapter = CargoListAdapter(this, arrayListOf())
adapter.onItemActionsListener = object  : CargoListAdapter.OnItemActionsListener {
                    override fun onDeleteClicked() {
                        // TODO logic
                    }
                }
```

CargoFragment

```
adapter = CargoListAdapter(requireActivity(), arrayListOf())
adapter.onItemActionsListener = object  : CargoListAdapter.OnItemActionsListener {
                    override fun onDeleteClicked() {
                        // TODO logic
                    }
                }
```

if you need to do the logic in the adapter, instead of context check, you can use enum.

```
public enum DeleteCaseEnum {
    NONE, CASE_1, CASE_2, CASE_3
}

open class CargoListAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var list: ArrayList<Cargo>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

var deleteCase:DeleteCaseEnum  = DeleteCaseEnum .NONE

   holder.binding.ibDelete.setOnClickListener {

            when (deleteCase) {
                is DeleteCaseEnum.CASE_1-> {
                 // TODO
                }
              
                is DeleteCaseEnum.CASE_2-> {
                 // TODO
                }
            }
```

OrderActivity

```
adapter = CargoListAdapter(this, arrayListOf())
adapter.deleteCase = DeleteCaseEnum.CASE_1
```

CargoFragment

```
adapter = CargoListAdapter(requireActivity(), arrayListOf())
adapter.deleteCase = DeleteCaseEnum.CASE_2
```